# Question about colorBy after data sorting

Tags: echarts

In [this example](https://www.makeapie.com/editor.html?c=x3PtAxXsNO&v=3) with universalTransition turned on, after the pie chart of colorBy:'data' is sorted, it is inconsistent with the corresponding relationship between labels and colors in the bar chart, how to make their colors consistent.

*Makepie will be out of service on February 15, you can run follow code on [ECharts examples editor](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/zh/editor).*

```js
const dataset = {
  dimensions: ['name', 'score'],
  source: [
    ['Hannah Krause', 314],
    ['Zhao Qian', 351],
  ]
};
const pieOption = {
  // dataset: [dataset],
  // 顺序排序数据
  dataset: [dataset].concat({
    transform: {
      type: 'sort',
      config: { dimension: 'score', order: 'desc' },
    },
  }),
  series: [
    {
      type: 'pie',
      // 通过 id 关联需要过渡动画的系列
      id: 'Score',
      radius: [0, '50%'],
      universalTransition: true,
      animationDurationUpdate: 1000,
      // 取排序后的数据
      datasetIndex: 1,
    }
  ]
};
const barOption = {
  dataset: [dataset],
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
  },
  yAxis: {},
  series: [
    {
      type: 'bar',
      // 通过 id 关联需要过渡动画的系列
      id: 'Score',
      // 每个数据都是用不同的颜色
      colorBy: 'data',
      encode: { x: 'name', y: 'score' },
      universalTransition: true,
      animationDurationUpdate: 1000
    }
  ]
};

option = barOption;

setInterval(() => {
  option = option === pieOption ? barOption : pieOption;
  // 使用 notMerge 的形式可以移除坐标轴
  myChart.setOption(option, true);
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dataset order by 'desc' on pie chart.
but it's not used on bar chart.
Maybe your two charts should be sorted in the same order

```
  dataset: [dataset].concat({
    transform: {
      type: 'sort',
      config: { dimension: 'score', order: 'desc' },
    },
  }),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know what you said, but I hope to get exactly how to achieve the consistency of color data correspondence when charts use different sorting rules.